# Probability: Counting Combinations

Tags: probability

Your statistics teacher announces a twenty-page reading assignment on Monday that is to be finished by Thursday morning. You intend to read the first x1 pages Monday, the next x2 pages Tuesday, and the final x3 pages Wednesday, 
where x1 + x2 + x3 = 20, and each xi >= 1. 
In how many ways can you complete the assignment

Comment: If you show us what you have tried someone may be able to use your work in providing hints or an answer.

Comment: I believe I am supposed to use the equation n!/(k!(n-k)!). I have tried 20!/(3!17!) but I don’t believe that is the correct way to approach the problem as that is not the correct answer and I believe that incorporates reading the pages in random order were they need to be read in order. I am kind of confused in general on how to go about doing this. The answer I was given for this problem was 171.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  This is a classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.  If you have to read at least one page each day, there are $19$ stopping points, of which you choose two.

Comment: Alright I managed to work it my problem out with that, thank you! But for a little spin what would you do if it was changed so the minimum you could read was 2 a day? So xi >= 2

Comment: You just imagine that you have $17$ pages to read with a minimum $1$ per day and use the same approach.  Similarly, if you didn't have to read any each day, you could add in three new pages and read $23$ at a minimum of $1$ per day.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help!